# How to pass information from app.showdialog

Tags: viewmodel, durandal, showdialog

From one of my viewmodel called "carData" i open popup like below

```
app.showDialog('viewmodels/task/main', "222").then(function () {
}
```

Now it opens viewmodel called "main" which has code for opening dialogue

```
define(['plugins/dialog'],


function (dialog) {

    var ctor = function () {
    };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function (data) {

        var self = this;

        this.close = function () {
            dialog.close(self, "Cancel");
        };


    };

    return ctor;
}
);
```

The view for this viewmodel "main" is as below which will call another view

```
 <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/task/carInfo'"></div>
```

Now i want pass information from viewModel "carData" to "carInfo" viewmodel.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing more info about structure of Your application it is hard to provide any meaningful solution. However I would suggest using [application-wide messaging](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html) for communication between view-models.

To do so we change the method closing dialog to

```
this.close = function () {
        app.trigger('dialog:closed', DATA_TO_SEND);
        dialog.close(self, "Cancel");
    };
```

Now in the 'carInfo' view-model You can subscribe to such a message and do some action in the moment of receiving it.

```
app.on('dialog:closed').then(function(data){
    //do something with the received data
});
```

Comment: you are passing trigger in close function. What will be use if dialog is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback to pass information from your dialog.

For example:

```
app.showDialog('viewmodels/task/main', "222").then(function (action, model) {
if (action == "save") {
 // save content from dialog
}
}
```